# Custom radio button not getting checked on clicking

Tags: html, css

I created a custom radio button using HTML and CSS

```css
.radio {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.radio__input {
  display: none;
}

.radio__radio {
  width: 1.25em;
  height: 1.25em;
  border: 2px solid #87cac3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
}

.radio__radio::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: #87cac3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}

.radio__input:checked+.radio__radio::after {
  transform: scale(1)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="myRadioId" class="radio">Agree</label>
  <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input">
  <div class="radio__radio"></div>
  </label>
</div>
```

The code doesn't seem to work accurately means, the radio button is not getting checked on clicking. I think the problem is with the .radio__radio::after inside it i have done trnsform: scale(0) so it should default change its scale to zero on refreshing the page and when checked it should change the scale to 1.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to close a html tag.

Comment: You shouldn't wrap the input inside `label` tag. close it on the second line.

Comment: Your snippet seems to work, the radio button gets center filled in when I click it. Could you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: @Shariar hi, I don’t understand why a label shouldn’t wrap an input.

Comment: It's perfect valid to have an `input` inside a `label` and it even creates a semantic link between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, hope it will be helpful .

```js
var val = 0;
$('input[name=myRadioField]').on("click", function(){
    console.log(val);
    if($(this).val()==val) 
    {$(this).prop('checked', false);
    val = -1;
    }
    else val = $(this).val();
});
```

```css
.radio {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.radio__input {
  display: none;
}

.radio__radio {
  width: 1.25em;
  height: 1.25em;
  border: 2px solid #87cac3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
}

.radio__radio::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: #87cac3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}

.radio__input:checked+.radio__radio::after {
  transform: scale(1)
}

.radio__input:unchecked+.radio__radio::after {
  transform: scale(0)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="myRadioId" class="radio">Agree
    <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input">  
    <div class="radio__radio"></div>
 </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your inputs.
The problem is solved I just added `autocomplete= "off"` inside `<input>` tag and it worked fine.

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.radio__input {
  display: none;
}

.radio__radio {
  width: 1.25em;
  height: 1.25em;
  border: 2px solid #87cac3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.radio__radio::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: #87cac3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}

.radio__input:checked+.radio__radio::after {
  transform: scale(1)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Question 1</h1>
  <h4>Agree
    <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input" autocomplete="off" value="1">  
            <div class="radio__radio"></div>
          </label>
    <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input" autocomplete="off" value="2">  
            <div class="radio__radio"></div>
          </label>
    <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input" autocomplete="off" value="3">  
            <div class="radio__radio"></div>
          </label>
    <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input" autocomplete="off" value="4">  
            <div class="radio__radio"></div>
          </label>
    <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="myRadioField" id="myRadioId" class="radio__input" autocomplete="off" value="5">  
            <div class="radio__radio"></div>
          </label> Disagree
  </h4>
</div>
```